# Как можно реализовать замену одних ссылок на другие pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telebot, ссылки, бот

Пишу бота на python с помощью библиотеки pytelegrambotapi и столкнулся с такой проблемой что не знаю как реализовать замену ссылок с одних на другие в пересылаемом пользователем посте(текст и фото)
Кто нибудь может подсказать как можно такое реализовать

Comment: Приведите пример

Comment: @Post_links_bot